# geom_histogram to plot counts/accumulation of each x value and higher

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, histogram, geom-bar

I am trying to create a histogram/bar plot in R to show the counts of each x value I have in the dataset **and higher**. I am having trouble doing this, and I don't know if I use geom_histogram or geom_bar (I want to use ggplot2). To describe my problem further:

On the X axis I have "Percent_Origins," which is a column in my data frame. On my Y axis - for each of the Percent_Origin values I have occurring, I want the height of the bar to represent the count of rows with that percent value and higher. Right now, if I am to use a histogram, I have:

```
   plot <- ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=dataframe$Percent_Origins)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=Percent_Origins), binwidth= .05, colour="white")
```

What should I change the fill or general code to be to do what I want? That is, plot an accumulation of counts of each value and *higher*? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add code to replicate the `dataframe` data set so we can understand what exactly you're asking?

Comment: are you after an empirical CDF plot?

Comment: I am looking into the stat ecdf parameter of histogram. This is what I have:

plot <- ggplot(assigned_origins, aes(x=assigned_origins$Percent_Origins)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = 1 - ..y..), stat='ecdf')

but now the y axis has decimal values instead of counts?

Comment: And yes, I want an empirical CDF plot, but reversed - so it accumulates everything at and *above* each x value.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet is going to be creating the cumulative distribution function *first* then passing it to `ggplot`. There are several ways to do this, but a simple one (using `dplyr`) is to sort the data (in descending order), then just assign a count for each. Trim the data so that only the largest count is still included, then plot it.

To demonstrate, I am using the builtin `iris` data.

```
iris %>%
  arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  mutate(counts = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(Sepal.Length) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = counts)) +
  geom_step(direction = "vh")
```

gives:

[image]

If you really want bars instead of a line, use `geom_col` instead. However, note that you either need to fill in gaps (to ensure the bars are evenly spaced across the range) or deal with breaks in the plot.